# GridView for calendar view

Tags: java, android, android-gridview, calendarview

Parts of my old app are deprecated, I am trying to rebuild it. Basically it is a Calendar with month view.
This is a part of my gridview adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    Date date = getItem(position);
    int day = date.getDate();
    int month = date.getMonth();
    int year = date.getYear();
}
```

and the `int day = date.getDate(); int month = date.getMonth(); int year = date.getYear();` 
are deprecated. I am trying to use the `Calendar` class instead of `Date` but unable to do the same. I know that for retrieve the day, month or year I can use this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

but I don't know how to convert this line:

```
Date date = getItem(position);
```

for using with `Calendar`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this line of code:

Just replace this line

```
Date date = getItem(position);
```

with this line:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Here is a full example for you:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = calendar.getTime();
int day =  calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month =  calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year =  calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you convert a `Date` object to a `Calendar` object:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```

Then (like you said) you can do:

```
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so it cannot done "natively" without using Date object only with Calendar object?

Comment: No prob. If you don't want to use `Date` then you will need to change your adapter data set to `Calendar` and make `getItem()` return `Calendar`.

Answer (score 1):

First you're gonna want to reference Calendar. Once you've done that, you can say `Date date = calendar.getTime`

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    int day =  calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month =  calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)    
    int year =  calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

Ok

To major sources:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html
2. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

`Date` is not deprecated. Only some methods.

So,

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    Date date = getItem(position);
    long ms = date.getTime();https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();//allowed
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(ms);//allowed https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis(long)
    //calendar.setTime(date); is also allowed https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime(java.util.Date)
    int day =  calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);//allowed 
    int month =  calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);//allowed  
    int year =  calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);//allowed 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code to convert from `Date` to `Calendar`.

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    Date date = getItem(position);
    // convert a Date object to a Calendar object
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);

    int day =  calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month =  calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year =  calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```